# Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem, when I run hibernate it shows me the error of `"Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.trein.Moneda.documento"`
, and the truth is I do not know why it is throwing this error.
It seems like its failing in `Moneda.java` class

**Documento.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pais_id", nullable = false)
private Pais pais;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "moneda_id", nullable = false)
private Moneda moneda;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "remesa_id", nullable = false)
private Remesa remesa_doc;
```

**Moneda.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "moneda")
private Documento documento;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are expecting that `Moneda` object has many `Documento` object then you should make it `List<Documento>` because `@OneToMany` annotation expects the property to be a `collection` of some objects.